# Using jquery in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails. I want to implement **[this](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form)** signup wizard in my application. i have copied the jquery to a file named **signup_validation.js** and included that file within /assets/javascripts folder.

I have included that HTML code within my view. Now how can i include that javascript file so that the signup wizard works in the same way like in the tutorial.

Here is the new.html.erb file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/signup_validation.js"></script>

<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <form id="example-advanced-form" action="#">
    <h3>Account</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <label for="userName-2">User name *</label>
        <input id="userName-2" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="password-2">Password *</label>
        <input id="password-2" name="password" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="confirm-2">Confirm Password *</label>
        <input id="confirm-2" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </fieldset>

    <h3>Profile</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profile Information</legend>

        <label for="name-2">First name *</label>
        <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="surname-2">Last name *</label>
        <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="email-2">Email *</label>
        <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
        <label for="address-2">Address</label>
        <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text">
        <label for="age-2">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
        <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </fieldset>

</form>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Here is the application.js file.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require signup_validation
```

Comment: Use `javascript_include_tag('signup_validation')` in your `<head>`?!?

Comment: No need to include it separately. Look in your application.js and there look at the lines that require other libraries. If you have `require tree .` you are all set already. Otherwise you can also go ahead and add the library to include there. Rails asset pipeline will do the concatenation for you and include your file automatically.

Comment: does it work after page refresh? => may be a turbolink issue?

Comment: @GaneshKumar Did you checked the view source. this file is actually included in page ?
Check view source

Comment: @GaneshKumar, I answered Your question . Please check it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the jquery below this file and it worked :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/signup_validation.js"></script>

<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <form id="example-advanced-form" action="#">
    <h3>Account</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

    <label for="userName-2">User name *</label>
    <input id="userName-2" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="password-2">Password *</label>
    <input id="password-2" name="password" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="confirm-2">Confirm Password *</label>
    <input id="confirm-2" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
    <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
</fieldset>

<h3>Profile</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Profile Information</legend>

    <label for="name-2">First name *</label>
    <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="surname-2">Last name *</label>
    <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
    <label for="email-2">Email *</label>
    <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
    <label for="address-2">Address</label>
    <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text">
    <label for="age-2">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
    <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
    <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
</fieldset>
```

```
<script>
var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();

form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
        if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
        if (currentIndex < newIndex)
        {
            // To remove error styles
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18)
        {
            form.steps("next");
        }
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
        {
            form.steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.submit();
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
}).validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password-2"
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Order in Application.js
Replce this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require signup_validation
```

With

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require signup_validation
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: **<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/signup_validation.js"></script>** do we need this code in new.html.erb file?

Comment: Can You tell me , Which files you get in view source ?
Can you find you code in view source ?

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: @GaneshKumar , Did you restart the server after updating this order ?

Comment: @GaneshKumar May be there are some spelling issue. because this is the perfact way. i tried it many time.